# Access / VBA - Are Form Properties keeping my tables open?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2007

UPDATE:
I've done some more testing and disabled the button I added, the form still will not close the connection when I close the form. I'm thinking it has more to do with the form properties then the code behind the button, or perhaps the button code and form have conflicting properties keeping the table open.

I also tried to set the rs = Nothing and db = Nothing after I close the connections in the VBA.

So i have a sub-form, that gets called by my Mainform. When this happens I try and populate some controls using the VBA code below. However, when i close the sub-form, and try and re-access the sub-form from the Mainform, it says :
[image: cporders2]

```
Private Sub CommandDupe_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 CPOrders.Cust, Customer.NAME, CPOrders.CP_Ref, CPOrders.Slsman, CPOrders.Date_opn, CPOrders.CPSmall, CPOrders.InvIssu, CPOrders.InvNo, CPOrders.InvDate, CPOrders.DueDate, CPOrders.ETADate, CPOrders.Closed, CPOrders.Cust, CPOrders.Name, CPOrders.BuyerRef, CPOrders.ToCity, CPOrders.ToState, CPOrders.ToCtry, CPOrders.ToPort, CPOrders.Supplier, CPOrders.Origin, CPOrders.Product, CPOrders.GradeType, CPOrders.NoUnits, CPOrders.Pkg, CPOrders.Qty, CPOrders.TotSale, CPOrders.TotCost, CPOrders.GrMargin, CPOrders.[Sale$/Unit], CPOrders.[Cost$/Unit], CPOrders.OceanCost, CPOrders.OceanNotes, CPOrders.BLadingDate, CPOrders.USAPort, CPOrders.FOBCost, CPOrders.FASExportVal, CPOrders.InlandFrt, CPOrders.CommodCode, CPOrders.Notes, CPOrders.ProjCust, CPOrders.ProjValue, CPOrders.ContainerNumber, CPOrders.Vessel, CPOrders.Ord_Terms, CPOrders.Invoice_ID FROM Customer INNER JOIN CPOrders ON Customer.[CUST_#] = CPOrders.Cust ORDER BY CPOrders.Invoice_ID desc;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
rs.MoveFirst


CP_Ref.Value = rs("CP_Ref")
Slsman.Value = rs("Slsman")
Date_opn.Value = rs("Date_opn")
CPSmall.Value = rs("CPSmall")
InvIssu.Value = rs("InvIssu")
InvNo.Value = rs("InvNo")
InvDate.Value = rs("InvDate")
DueDate.Value = rs("DueDate")
Cust.Value = rs("Cust")
BuyerRef.Value = rs("BuyerRef")
ToCity.Value = rs("ToCity")
ToState.Value = rs("ToState")
ToCtry.Value = rs("ToCtry")
ToPort.Value = rs("ToPort")
Product.Value = rs("Product")
Supplier.Value = rs("Supplier")
GradeType.Value = rs("GradeType")
Origin.Value = rs("Origin")
NoUnits.Value = rs("NoUnits")
Pkg.Value = rs("Pkg")
Qty.Value = rs("Qty")
TotSale.Value = rs("TotSale")
TotCost.Value = rs("TotCost")
OceanCost.Value = rs("OceanCost")
OceanNotes.Value = rs("OceanNotes")
BLadingDate.Value = rs("BLadingDate")
USAPort.Value = rs("USAPort")
FOBCost.Value = rs("FOBCost")
Notes.Value = rs("Notes")
InlandFrt.Value = rs("InlandFrt")
CommodCode.Value = rs("CommodCode")
Vessel.Value = rs("Vessel")
ContainerNumber.Value = rs("ContainerNumber")
ProjCust.Value = rs("ProjCust")
ProjValue.Value = rs("ProjValue")


rs.Close
db.Close
```

As you can see I do close the rs and the db...what else can i do to make sure this connection is closed after I close the sub-form? I need to be able to access this from the MainForm consistently.

Thanks in advance!!!
Also I added the form properties of the form that does not close[image]

Comment: try `set rs = Nothing` and `set db = Nothing` at the end of your code

Comment: also, it may be a good idea to open the record set as a snapshot: `set rs = db.openRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)`

Comment: i set them to nothing and that did not help...let me try snapshot

Comment: I used Snapshot, it performs a little slower, and still got the same issue...@Barranka

Comment: @Barranka is there some way I could set the values without having that connection string open?

Comment: @Barranka it seems like this effects it even if i don't press the Duplicate button we designed...So the button is creating a connection even though it's not being pressed.

Comment: @Barranka does this have to do with the fact that my form properties record source is tied to another query? IS there some way i can just reference that one? instead of using the one I wrote in previous question?

Comment: What happens if you change the form's Record Locks property from "All Records" to "No Locks"?

Comment: It makes the form read-only @HansUp

Comment: Does that mean there's an error in the table? Why would a nolock restrict it to read only...wouldn't that in fact make it write-ready?

Comment: That surprised me and I'm baffled.  Can you upload a copy of that db somewhere?

Comment: Do you have Skype? we can talk through this more...Could there be an error record in the table?

Comment: Sorry, no Skype.  But I doubt that really matters.  I ... oops ... I got mail!  Later.